# BCrypt from Scratch

Tags: javascript, hash, bcrypt, game-maker, gml

I'm sad to say that I'm working in a proprietary language that doesn't have bcrypt support. It has md5 and sha1, but not bcrypt, which I think is the better option. I've never had to deal with passwords in this language before, so it's never been a problem. I've used bcrypt in other languages, so I'm fairly familiar with how it works.

In short, I'd like to make a bcypt algorithm, so that I can package it and solve this problem for other developers using the same language.

The language itself is purely procedural, and the syntax looks a lot like JavaScript. I'm fairly certain that I can convert a JavaScript solution to fit my needs, however I'm willing to accept answers in C++, C#, PHP, Java, Python, and Lua (As I know these languages fairly well) as well, as long as no native functions are used (Mathy things are probably fine), as I may not be able to replicate those.

Are there any libraries out there that do this? I'm currently working off of the Wikipedia page for bcrypt, but having a concrete example would be extremely useful.

For the curious ones, the language I'm using is GML.

Comment: Where is the question? This looks like a request for code which a quick google search should handle.

Comment: I've been searching, and I can't find a solution that doesn't use any native functions. For example there's a PHP solution for 5.3, but it relies on the `crypt ` function.

Comment: Literally the first google result for "bcrypt javascript"
https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js

Comment: I'm currently looking into that, to see if I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [bcrypt.js for Node.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js) is a bit dependency heavy. Since you're planning on converting it, that might be a headache.

Personally, I recommend looking into [nevin-b's bCrypt.js](https://github.com/nevins-b/javascript-bcrypt/blob/master/bCrypt.js). As far as I can tell, it doesn't have any dependencies.

Comment: I ended up using this. Thanks.